# Compute highest and lowest occurrence of relationship in one query [Neo4j]

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to compute the highest and lowest occurrence of co authorship relationship between authors over specific years with cypher using the
`WHERE` clause, with an array of years. When testing only one value in array of years, i get the right values, but with more years in array, the counting of `minAmount` and `maxAmount` are accumulating all years, then things become wrong.

The following code working with one year in array:

```
MATCH (i:Institution{name:'UnB'})-[rel:ASSOCIATED_TO]-(a1:Author)[co:COAUTHOR]-(a2:Author) WHERE co.year IN [2018]

WITH a1,count (co) as amount

WITH MIN(amount) as minAmount, MAX(amount) as maxAmount

return  minAmount,maxAmount
```

I tried to use `FOREACH`,`CASE` and others to loop over years in array of years and compute the highest and lowest BY YEAR separated, but without success.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `COLLECT(co)` instead of `COUNT(co)` if you want to use `MIN` and `MAX`

Comment: Are you trying to find how many coauthorships each author had for each year in the list (in which case min/max makes no sense), or the min/max coauthorships for *each* author for all years in the list, or the min/max coauthorships for *any* author for all years in the list, or something else?